# Embedding Kivy into existing iOS/Android native applications

Tags: android, ios, kivy, embedding

I have existing native iOS and Android apps (Swift and Kotlin, respectively).

I also have an existing, standalone, cross-platform kivy app.

I'd like to know if there is a way to embed the kivy app into the native apps, e.g. by isolating the kivy app into its own ViewController/Activity. For my purposes, it's fine for kivy to take the whole screen, I don't need to put it inside its own view.

I looked at the kivy docs, but they don't seem to cover this use case. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Brother did you find any solution?